# PHP usort in golang

Tags: go

Is there a `usort` from PHP in go? I need to give it either -1, 0, or 1.
For example in PHP:

```php
<?php

function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$array = array('a' => 4, 'b' => 8, 'c' => -1, 'd' => -9, 'e' => 2, 'f' => 5, 'g' => 3, 'h' => -4);
usort($array, 'cmp');
print_r($array);
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: I try Swap but is bool instead int

Comment: There is no standard function in Go that is **identical by its behaviour and signature** to php's `usort`.